# How to extend selection in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Currently it works like this: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/make-extend-selection/
However I want it to expand like in VScode where I can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> the <kbd>↓</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> keys, and that will expand one row each press and not the entire paragraph. How can that be achieved in PyCharm?

Comment: Mm, do you mean shift+up/down?

Comment: yes like in vscode or in any editor like word and stuff..

Comment: Well, Shift+up/shift+down extends the selection by lines in PyCharm for me. See the "Move Caret to Line End with Selection" action in the Keymap configuration.

Comment: `ctrl + shift + down arrow` is not the same functionality as `ctrl + shift + right arrow`...